# Change compiler called in makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, icc

I have a make file that currently uses `cmake` to compile a collection of source files, but I would like to change it so it uses intel's c compiler. Can I just change all the `cmake` to `icc` or...how would this be done?

Below is the make file as-is, it's from a crypto-mining daemon for bytecoin.

```
all: all-release

cmake-debug:
    mkdir -p build/debug
    cd build/debug && cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../..

build-debug: cmake-debug
    cd build/debug && $(MAKE)

test-debug: build-debug
    cd build/debug && $(MAKE) test

all-debug: build-debug

cmake-release:
    mkdir -p build/release
    cd build/release && cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../..

build-release: cmake-release
    cd build/release && $(MAKE)

test-release: build-release
    cd build/release && $(MAKE) test

all-release: build-release

clean:
    rm -rf build

tags:
    ctags -R --sort=1 --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --language-force=C++ src contrib tests/gtest

.PHONY: all cmake-debug build-debug test-debug all-debug cmake-release build-release test-release all-release clean tags
```

I can post the other files it creates in /build after a normal build, if that would help, but I imagine whatever process I have to do to change the compiler would be the same for each MAKE file.

Otherwise, the rest of the source files can be found here:

https://github.com/amjuarez/bytecoin

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify your toolchain settings for CMake using a [`toolchain.txt`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#id6) file with the `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=path/to/file` on the first call of CMake, that generates the makefiles:

```
cmake -G"Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=<path_to>/toolchain.txt
```

There should be entries like

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /<your-toolchain-path>/gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /<your-toolchain-path>/g++)
```

in `toolchain.txt`.

Comment: How would I specify these settings in the existing make file? I presume I would put the toolchain.txt file in the same directory as the makefile but how do I tell the makefile to read it (or would it happen automatically)?

Comment: @Eric You specify in the file given with the `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=path/to/file` option, I'll update my answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Typically `CXX=<mycompiler> cmake` should do what you want. Or you can modify the toolchain files of the project, assuming you want to permanently make the change.

This is my script that runs cmake to build llvm/clang with clang and clang++:

```
CC=clang CXX=clang++ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release\ 
-DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=1  -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86 ../llvm
```

Comment: Can I just add that at the beginning of the existing make file? `CXX=icc cmake`?

Comment: In `bash` or similar, if you type `name=x`, then the environment variable `name` is set. Since cmake uses the environment variables to determine what compiler to use, it should just pick the new compiler that way.